# Personal questionnaire using JavaScript prompts

Tags: javascript, beginner

This is just playing around and practicing javascript. I am learning JavaScript from Codecademy and I practice coding everyday so I can learn much as possible. I have a lot of `if` statements, prompt boxes, some alert boxes. I just got finished learning about functions and returns. I just don't know how to use the return in a browser for like `document.write` or even an alert box.

```
function prompter() {
    var toc = prompt("What do you prefer? Tea or Coffee");
    if ((toc == "tea") || (toc == "Tea")) {

    } else if ((toc == "coffee") || (toc == "Coffee")) {

    }
    var foc = prompt("What do you prefer? Facebook or MySpace");
    if ((foc == "facebook") || (foc == "Facebook")) {

    } else if ((foc == "myspace") || (foc == "Myspace")) {

    }
    document.write("<center><h2>So you like " + toc + " and " + foc + " that is awesome.</h2></center>");
}

function pickAColour() {
    var fun = prompt("What is your favorite colour? , mine is red.");
    document.write("<center><h2>You like the colour " + fun + " that is a nice colour</h2></center>");
}

function pickANumber() {
    alert("Lets do some math, do you like Math?");
    var pan = prompt("Please pick a number");
    var nap = prompt("Please pick another number");
    var symbol = prompt("Please pick one of the following symbols +  -  *  /");
    pan = parseInt(pan); //The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.
    nap = parseInt(nap); //The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.
    if (symbol == "+") {
        alert("You picked the Add symbol");
        alert("Lets add both these numbers together. " + pan + " " + symbol + " " + nap);
        document.write("<center>Your number is " + (pan + nap) + "</center>");
    }
    if (symbol == "-") {
        alert("You picked the Minus symbol");
        alert("Lets Minus both of these numbers. " + pan + " " + symbol + " " + nap);
        document.write("<center>Your number is " + (pan - nap) + "</center>");
    }
    if (symbol == "*") {
        alert("You picked the Multiply symbol");
        alert("Lets Multiply both these numbers. " + pan + " " + symbol + " " + nap);
        document.write("<center>Your number is " + (pan * nap) + "</center>");
    }
    if (symbol == "/") {
        alert("You picked the Divide symbol");
        alert("Lets Divide both these numbers. " + pan + " " + symbol + " " + nap);
        document.write("<center>Your number is " + (pan / nap) + "</center>");
    }
}

function run() {
    var name = prompt("What is your name?");
    document.write("<h1><center>Welcome to this special JavaScript page " + name + "</center></h1>");
    prompter();
    pickAColour();
    pickANumber();
    document.write("<center>Thank You for visting this page</center>");
}

run();
```

Comment: ... good going! I'd suggest making friends with [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) if you have not already. It picks up a lot of piddly stuff that if you learn to avoid early on, will help develop clarity and adherence to best practices. When practicable that is ;-)

Comment: Any learning resource that teaches you to use document.write should be shunned and avoided.

Comment: You should definitely try http://www.codeschool.com/courses/jquery-air-first-flight for learning about much better ways of manipulating your web pages.  It's like Code Academy on steroids.

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be on the right track, at least with grasping how to do some basic coding.

Right now, I only see one major issue: `document.write()`

`document.write()` is used to build pages out of javascript, something that is both impractical and ill-advised (in almost every situation). Moving forward, you should start building your pages in HTML and use javascript to tweak the page from that point.

To do this, you will want to replace `document.write()` with `document.getElementById()`. Lets look at an example:

You have the following HTML block:

```
<h1 id='welcome'></h1>
```

Now, to insert text into this block, we would do something like this:

```
var welcomeElement = document.getElementById('welcome');
welcomeElement.innerHTML = "This is my welcome message!";
```

There's many things you can do with elements once you have gotten them, but I'll leave that for a later experiment.

---

At this point, I'll leave you to learn how to update your code. If you get confused or stuck however, you can view my rendition of your code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/danthegoodman/v7gLE/

Answer (score 3):

1. variables names that are three letter abbreviations aren't helpful when you come back. Don't be concerned about the number of characters (within reason) for your names.

   `teaOrCoffeeAnswer` is easier to read or even `drinkAnswer`
2. I'm surprised no-one has pointed this out but `"somestring".toLowerCase()` can help you heaps. (or `.toUpperCase()`) Its a good thing to try and find some built in functions if it seems like something that would be common.

   ```
   turns 

   if ((toc == "tea") || (toc == "Tea")) {

   } else if ((toc == "coffee") || (toc == "Coffee")) {

   }
   ```

   into

   ```
   if (toc == "tea"){

   } else if (toc == "coffee") {

   }
   ```

   I'd suggest something like:

   ```
   var drinkAnswer = prompt("What do you prefer? Tea or Coffee");
   drinkAnswer = (drinkAnswer || "").toLowerCase();
   if (drinkAnswer == "tea") {

   } else if (drinkAnswer == "coffee") {

   }
   ```

   *(the* `drinkAnswer || ""` *means that you won't get a null reference exception.)*
3. `parseInt()` has a "hidden" feature. it turns any string beginning with "0" into an octal number (base 8). Assume your user always enters a decimal number and instead force the method to parse in decimal (base 10)

   ```
   parseInt(numberAsString, 10);
   ```

   this will save a lot of headaches later.

Comment: On 3, I would in the end suggest [using + to coerce an integer value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2243631/148412) instead of sending the base-10 into parseInt: `var number = +inputFromUser;`

Comment: @ANeves I personally don't find that very intuitive for a JavaScript learner to put in their "toolkit". It doesn't always act the way you expect. (e.g. `+" "`)

Comment: Oh. Scratch that, then, and back to `parseInt(foo, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this - I modified and left a couple of comments. You're on the right path :)

```
function stristr (haystack, needle) {
    var pos = 0
    haystack += ''

    pos = haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf((needle + '').toLowerCase())
    if (pos >= 0) return haystack.substr(0, pos)
}

function prompter() {
    var toc, foc /* Define your variables up here, not in body */

    /* No need for empty if/else statements - if you need them in the future, 
     * use (stristr(toc) == "tea") for example. */
    toc = prompt("What do you prefer? Tea or Coffee")
    foc = prompt("What do you prefer? Facebook or MySpace")

    /* Let's add some really basic error checking */
    toc != "" ? toc = "like " + toc : toc = "don't like tea or coffee "
    foc != "" ? foc = " you like " + foc : foc = " you don't like Facebook or MySpace"

    /* <center> is deprecated :) */
    document.write("<h2 style='text-align:center'>So you " + toc + " and " + foc + ". That is awesome.</h2>")
}

function pickAColour() {
    /* 'fun' is not an appropriate descriptive variable name, lets change it to 'color' */
    var color = prompt("My favorite color is red. What is your favorite colour?")

    /* <center> is deprecated :) */
    document.write("<h2 style='text-align:center'>You like the colour " + color + " that is a nice colour</h2>")
}

function pickANumber() {
    var firstNumber, secondNumber, symbol, problem, answer

    /* Don't ask 'Do you like math?" as the user will then expect an input to answer that question */
    alert("Lets do some math.")
    pan = prompt("Please pick a number")
    nap = prompt("Please pick a second number")
    symbol = prompt("Please pick one of the following symbols +  -  *  /")

    /* Get rid of the parseInt calls and re-store and just set a problem string for later usage */
    problem = parseInt(pan) + " " + symbol + " " + parseInt(nap)

    /* Let's get an answer while we're at it */
    answer = eval(problem)

    /* Let's make life easier and get the symbol name via a switch statement */
    switch(symbol){
        case "+" : symbolWord = "addition"
            break
        case "-" : symbolWord = "subtraction"
            break
        case "*" : symbolWord = "multiplication"
            break
        case "/" : symbolWord = "division"
            break
    }

    alert ("You picked the " + symbolWord + " symbol")
    alert ("The math problem you chose was: " + problem)
    alert ("The answer to the problem you chose is " + answer)
}

function run() {
    var name = prompt("What is your name?")
    document.write("<h1><center>Welcome to this special JavaScript page " + name + "</center></h1>")
    prompter()
    pickAColour()
    pickANumber()
    document.write("<center>Thank You for visting this page</center>")
}

run()
```

.

```
                         ==--==--==--== EDIT EDIT EDIT ==--==--==--==
```

To answer a comment below - true - semicolons should be used as they are in many other languages. I guess I've been spending too much time with python lately :)

As Danny said - it is indeed a Ternary Operator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) and its basically a short hand if/else statement. Like this:

```
trueOrFalseStatementHere ? ifTrueDoThis : ifFalseDoThis
```

example:

```
(1 + 1 == 2) ? print "1 plus 1 is 2" : print "1 plus 1 is not 2"
```

For your question on the stristr function - its basically a replica of the PHP stristr function.

```
function stristr (haystack, needle) {
    var pos = 0
    haystack += ''

    pos = haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf((needle + '').toLowerCase())
    if (pos >= 0) return haystack.substr(0, pos)
}
```

It does indeed turn everything to lower case - that way you don't have to check the user input for every single case...for example, with your old method, if the user entered "coFFee", it would not pick it up since you were only checking for "Coffee" and "coffee"...but with this stristr function, the user input "coFFee" would become "coffee" and you only have to check for 1 case: "coffee". See the PHP manual's definition of `stristr` for a more accurate explanation http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php.

With your method, you would have to check for 9 variations of "tea"

Comment: I personally find better to use semicolons always as it has a big impression on many languages like Java or C# etc.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.  I am searching a few things you have added, trying to understand some of them.  The first one would be the stristr function, does it take the answers from the prompt and lowercase all the letters?.  Next thing I don't understand is the basic error checking, toc !="" ? toc = "" part.  I know ! means is not, but I havn't seen $ yet.  Thanks again.

Comment: That's called the [Terenary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) and is common for short conditional statements. That section could be expanded to this:

`if (toc != "") { toc = "like " + toc } else { toc = "don't like tea or coffee " }`

Comment: @YasinOkumus Even in JavaScript, if you don't use semicolons, some statements won't get parsed the way you expected. I think you should always use semicolons because of that (one less pitfall to worry about).

Comment: @svick Thank you very much. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: See edited answer for more details and answers to comments here.

Comment: Generally, it's good practice to avoid using the ternary operator unless assigning a value. There's a lot of debate about this, but [see this StackOverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248920/expressions-in-javascript-ternary-operator-and-jslint) for some interesting arguments.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis I'd generally agree with you

Comment: All this information is great, will be looking over this over and over.  Thanks everyone.  I also seemed to learn that <pre> var e = document.getElementById('color');
    e.innerHTML = "You like the colour " + fun + " that is a nice colour";<code>  Doesn't seem to work in IE 9, but it is still great to know, and everyone says alert boxs is best to test with.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to put code into code tags.

Comment: Yep, some browsers don't support certain features or ways that features are scripted. 

By the way - to put code in code tags in comments, use the backtick ` followed by four spaces, then your code, then another backtick.

Comment: @SamSatanas , `code` : use a back-tick (`) to open the code and another to close it.

Comment: Yea, I just found out that you can't use `document.getElementById` in a loop ether.  I wanted it to print out 1-10 just like `document.write`.

Comment: @SamSatanas - I don't see why document.getElementById shouldn't work in a loop...

Comment: @jsanc623 I been searching all morning on google, I found some where that document.getElementById only prints once. In which it did, it printed number 10 on screen in stead of number 1, number 2 etc. Like a for loop.